# How to express distinctness of objects in mathematical logic

Tags: logic

How do I write the following statement logically:

There does not exist distinct $x_1, x_2 \in S$ such that $u = \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2, 0<\lambda<1$.

My attempt: $\nexists [(x_1,x_2\in S \wedge x_1 \neq x_2)\forall \lambda\in(0,1) u = \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2] $

My main confusion is with where the brackets go and how we express "distinct $x_1, x_2 \in S$" using logic.

Comment: $x_1\in S_1,x_2\in S_2,S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$ is one way in math.

Comment: I'm confused; what is $S_1, S_2$?  I wanted to show that two distinct elements in the set have a certain property, not elements in different sets

Comment: $S_1,S_2$ are sets forming a partition of set $S$ this is why they are disjoint.

Answer (score 3):

Two points are distinct means they are not the same. So, if they are not distinct, they are equivalent. In other words, if the two points satisfy your given condition, they must be equivalent.
$$\forall x_1 x_2 \in S,(\lambda \in (0,1) \wedge u = \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2 \implies x_1 = x_2).$$
I believe your statement is fine with a little tweaking.
$$\not\exists x_1,x_2 \in S,\lambda \in (0,1) \wedge u = \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2 \wedge x_1 \neq x_2$$

Comment: Thank you. So how would the negation of your statement look like?

Comment: The same as the negation of your statement :)